# Cambiar query por procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#

Tego el siguiente método Post para hacer un insert mediante APIS

```
public string Post (Department dep)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = @" Inster into  dbo.Department values(' "+dep.DepartmentName+@"   ') ";
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["EmployeeAppDB"].ConnectionString))
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.Fill(table);
                }
                return "Added SuccessFully";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Failed to Add!! ";
            }
        }
```

Lo que quiero es quitar el query y cambiarlo por procedimientos almacenados y enviar el parámetro, he intentado pero no consigo como hacerlo

```
 string query = @" Inster into  dbo.Department values(' "+dep.DepartmentName+@"   ') ";
```

Antes lo hacia así pero ahora no se como implementar esto en este método

```
 command.CommandText = "SP_ListarCanasta";
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guia", guia);
```

Comment: Intenta añadiendo `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: cual es el parametro que espera tu store procedure?

Comment: Manny   Es @Department

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trata de esta manera:

```html
public string Post (Department dep)
        {
            try
            {
             
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeAppDB"].ConnectionString))
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_Nombre,con))//SP_Nombre es el nombre de tu store procedure

                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", dep.DepartmentName);//aqui poner la @Department que espera el dato en tu SP mientras que guia es tu dato que le enviaras desde C#
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    da.Fill(table);
                }
                return "Added SuccessFully";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Failed to Add!! ";
            }
        }
```

Intentalo asi y comentas, a menos que falten mas datos esto deberia de funcionar

Comment: Me devuelve esto Added SuccessFully probando desde POSTMAN, pero hago un SELECT y nunca fue insertado

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada. capture el error

Comment: abre la conexion con.Open(); despues del sqlcommand

Comment: adite la respuesta